# How to us app.post event (from express) to write a message to clients with socket.write?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to send a message from a input field in a html form to all clients connected to the server when one of the clients posts something in the input field (textbox). I want to use the socket.write function because I have a raw TCP client connected to the server. 
I tried to use the Express library with the Post event because I want that kind of behaviour but can't use socket e.g. `socket.write` function inside of the `app.post` function.

Here is what I currently have on the server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
socket.write(' + req.body.name + ');
socket.pipe(socket);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res)  {
res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
//How to do this here?? 
server.socket.write(' + req.body.name + ')
socket.end();

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
});
//Thought of using a different server port for the raw TCP device
server.listen(2000, '127.0.0.1');
```

And a html form on the client side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contact">
<h1>Send an email</h1>
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/myaction" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your      name" />

        <label for="email">Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Your surname" />

        <input type="submit" value="Send" />

    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to do the `socket.write` on the `app.post event`. And can the name from the input field be sent using `socket.write`.

Sorry if i am missing something, I am new to this kind of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of your TCP clients. Try this:

```
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app        = express();
var net        = require('net');

// All your clients
var clients = [];

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

    // Track the client
    clients.push(socket);

    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        // Handle data coming from clients here
    });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.post('/myaction', function(req, res)  {
    res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');

    broadcast('New name:' + req.body.name);
});


// Here's where you send data to all clients
function broadcast(msg) {
   clients.forEach(function (client) {
      client.write(msg);
   });
}


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
});
//Thought of using a different server port for the raw TCP device
server.listen(2000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Great stuff. Wouldn't thought of this for a while.

Comment: My pleasure, mark it as correct answer if it solved your problem